# natbib's \citep does not work properly

Tags: natbib, overleaf

When using overleaf, natbib's \citep does not function. Part of my code:

```
\documentclass[9pt, a4paper]{article}

    % standard packages
    \usepackage{titlesec,color,rotating,booktabs,graphicx,natbib}    % standard packages
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}          % extra colors 
    
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    % PAGE MARGINS
    \usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=3.17cm, right=3.17cm]{geometry}
    
    % FONT (similar to Verdana)
    \usepackage[lf]{berenis}
    \renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} 
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    % for other fonts, and how to install them, see the LaTeX Font Catalogue:
    % http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/
    
    % LINE SPACE
    \linespread{1.1}                          % more space between lines
    \setlength{\parindent}{5mm}               % indenting first line paragraph
    
    % HYPHENATION (afbreekstreepjes)
    \usepackage[english]{babel}                                      % correct hyphenation (afbreekstreepjes)
    % set words that are not abbreviated correctly  (expand list when necessary)
    \hyphenation{catch-ment areas a-na-lyse}
    
    % Blue headers
    %\definecolor{wurblue}{cmyk}{1.0,0,0,0.58}
    \usepackage{sectsty}
    \allsectionsfont{\color{CornflowerBlue}}
    
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    
    
    \begin{document}
        
    
    \section{Problem description}
     \citep{PlasticFate}.
    
    \\\
    
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{References} 
    \bibliographystyle{elsart-harv}
    \bibliography{referencesthesis}
     \end{document}
```

I already tried to 'recompile everything multiple times, but without any succes.

Comment: Does your document even compile without errors? I have no `elsart-harv.bst` on my system, but I have `elsarticle-harv`

Comment: Goedemiddag, what exactly do you mean with 'does not work properly'? Do you get an error? If so, which one? Or do you get wrong output? If so, which output do you get?

Comment: @daleif Ys thanks! Adjusting elsart-harv.bst to elsarticle-harv indeed resolves all the question marks in the text. The only struggle left is that websites are displayed in a chaotic manner.  Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Sadly, i have no idea how to insert a picture of the layout.

Comment: That is probably a different question and not related to this. Please post a new question and provide samples of your bib data. If you're citing websites with standard bibtex then there is no specific support. One can manually use the `@misc` type.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a typo. I have no `elsart-harv.bst` on my system, but I have `elsarticle-harv.bst`

I don't use Overleaf, so I don't know how it shows bibtex errors, but in general never ignore compilation errors (`bibtex` is here an aux tool of the compilation).